# Ionic 2 Tabs: Hiding tab icon

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a tab layout and I'd like to hide a tab, but when I do that, the view will not show anything.  I thought `[show]` was for the icon, not the view.

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs id="myTabs" [selectedIndex]="0">
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Menu" [root]="menuPage" [rootParams]="clientParams" [show]="false"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

^ this displays nothing but removing the `[show]="false"` makes the view appear like normal.

**Is there a way to allow the view to be seen while removing the icon from the tab bar?**

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question is confusing of what you are trying to do. But I will try to answer the part of **"how to remove icon from tab bar"**

Normally if you do not have the **`tabIcon`** property in the `ion-tab` tag there wont have any icon show.

However if the tab icon is still showing for you you can set **`tabsLayout`** to `icon-hide` to hide the icon.

```
<ion-tabs tabsLayout="icon-hide">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Reference: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/